# Replacement for the old Acronym module in EE?

Tags: expressionengine

Are there any add-ons out there for EE 2 that can replace the old EE 1 Acronym module? It allowed you to build a database of acronyms that you could actually replace with anything, including linked text. So I was using it on a section of my site where I frequently needed to link to the same places. With the module, I could insert the acronyms whenever I needed a link and easily get that sorted. It also allowed me to edit those links easily if a link changed by editing in the database instead of in every post using it.

Comment: Have you checked in with Solspace if an EE2 version is in the works?

Comment: I remember that module, but don't know of anything that replaced it.

Comment: I did ask Solspace quite some time ago, and I don't think they had any plans for it, unfortunately.